# Написание школьных оценок

Tags: орфография, ономастика, пунктуация

Нужно ли брать в кавычки написанные прописью школьные оценки?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Иногда на письме школьные оценки действительно берутся в кавычки, однако для этого нет оснований. Это не название, не необычное слово, кроме того, орфографические словари также не выделяют эти слова кавычками.
Поэтому школьные оценки в кавычки брать не стоит.
Примеры: *двойка, пятерка*.

Comment: А если "два", "пять"?  
Ученик получил за ответ "пять".